# Why won't my loop end?

Tags: java, loops, libgdx

in the game I am making, I have a loop that runs in the show method of my libgdx screen.  The loop basically says that combat is going.  It is a while loop, that runs while the boolean "iscombat = true".  However, in the loop I put in a condition for iscombat to = false, and it doesn't seem to matter.  The loop keeps going.  I thought maybe I was making some sort of mistake so I put in an incrementing integer and told the loop to end when that integer to hit 30.  Loop keeps going.

So then I wrote for it to print out the value of the integer in case it wasn't incrementing.  Nope, I was watch as it goes above 30 and the loop still doesn't end.  So then I wrote in for the program to literally change screens when that integer goes above 30, and it STILL just keeps running the loop, even though it's printing out that the integer goes above 30.

Here is the code for the while loop:

```
while(combatisgoing = true){                                         //begin the combat loop.  all of combat happens in this loop?
blah++;    
System.out.println(blah);
thisencounter.TurnCounter();                                        //we are in combat now, so start the turn counting 

if(blah > 30){((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new Home());}
if(blah > 30){  combatisgoing = false; }

if(thisencounter.monster1turn=true){                                //monster1's turn goes in here
    thiscombat.getTarget(1);                                        //get enemy's target
    thiscombat.calculateVars(1);                                     //calculate all combat variables for this turn
    thiscombat.doAttack();
    System.out.println(Encounter.enemies.get(0).species+"attacked");
    System.out.println("Your spirits healths are:"+OwnedSpirits.myspirits.get(0).health+""+OwnedSpirits.myspirits.get(1).health+OwnedSpirits.myspirits.get(2).health);
thisencounter.monster1turn=false;
}    

}
```

There is more code than this but the other stuff isn't relevant at all.
If you want to see what turncounter looks like, I don't see why it matters but here it is

```
 public void TurnCounter(){
    x=0;
    while(x==0){
    monster1rate = monster1rate + monster1rate2;
    monster2rate = monster2rate + monster2rate2;
    monster3rate = monster3rate + monster3rate2;
    spirit1rate = spirit1rate + spirit1rate2;
    spirit2rate = spirit2rate + spirit2rate2;
    spirit3rate = spirit3rate + spirit3rate2;

if(monster1rate > 100000){

  monster1rate = monster1rate - 100000;
  monster1turn = true;
  x=1;
}
else if(monster2rate > 100000){

  monster1rate = monster1rate - 100000;
  monster2turn = true;
  x=1;
}
else if(monster3rate > 100000){

  monster1rate = monster1rate - 100000;
  monster3turn = true;
  x=1;
}
else if(spirit1rate > 100000){

  spirit1rate = spirit1rate - 100000;
  spirit1turn = true;
  x=1;
}
if(spirit2rate > 100000){

  spirit2rate = spirit2rate - 100000;
  spirit2turn = true;
  x=1;
}
if(spirit3rate > 100000){

  spirit3rate = spirit3rate - 100000;
  spirit3turn = true;
  x=1;
}



}
}
```

It's just a way of determining who's turn it is in my game.

The output for the game just shoots out, it increments all the way up and by the time I sto pit it looks something like this:

```
"Red Sadsackattacked
Your spirits healths are:151715
your spirit3 would go now
793
Red Sadsackattacked
Your spirits healths are:151715
your spirit3 would go now
794
Red Sadsackattacked
Your spirits healths are:151715
your spirit3 would go now
795
Red Sadsackattacked
Your spirits healths are:151715
your spirit3 would go now
796
Red Sadsackattacked
Your spirits healths are:151715
your spirit3 would go now
797
Red Sadsackattacked
Your spirits healths are:151715
your spirit3 would go now
798"
```

Which is exactly what I expect my output to look like other than that the loop isnt stopping when blah > 30.

Please help lol

Comment: You must walk before you run young grasshopper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an assignment that is always `true`

```
while (combatisgoing = true) {
```

Change it to

```
while (combatisgoing) {
```

Comment: How do I properly write that then?  It seems counterintuitive that this is always true but there is a lot I don't know as you can probably tell :P

Comment: Works like a charm and the world has became a wonderful place again.  I am curious why the language would be made so that you can assign a value in the condition for the while loop though.

Comment: It's similar to how you can do `for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {...}` In fact, you *could* use a normal assignment statement like that, as long as the variable was already defined, as you experienced.

Comment: @TravisBlack, it's not counter-intuitive if you realize you're "saying" "assign the value of this to that". Don't you always want that to be true?

Comment: @TravisBlack `combatisgoing = true` is allowed as a boolean simply to allow chaining of boolean types, e.g. `myboolean1 = myboolean2 = true`

Answer (score 0):

If `while(combatisgoing)`
is confusing for you...
Try `while(combatisgoing==true)`

One equals means that you are setting a value. In this case you are making combatisgoing to always be true.  Two equals is the operator that tells whether or not something is equivalent.